# How to resolve issue : Server terminated early with status 0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

Node version: 10.13.0 
npm version: 6.4.1

Output from running the test:

```
$ npm run e2e

> protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js

[15.11.04] W/launcher - You have specified both capabilitties and multicapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored
[15.11.04] W/launcher - Running 1 Instances of Webdriver
[15.11.04] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error: Server terminated early with status 0
[15.11.08] W/launcher - BUG: Launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
npm verb stack Error: 'protractor test/protractor.conf.js'
npm verb stack Exit status 100
```

- Chrome navigator version: **87.0.4280**
- Selenium server Standalone version:

> npm install http://path/selenim-server-3.141.59.tgz

- chromedriver version:

> npm install http://path/chromdriver-2.46.0.tgz

Comment: Can you show your `test/protractor.conf.js` code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

first thing I see is

> You have specified both capabilitties and multicapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored

Make sure it is not causing your problem

Second, chromdriver-2.46.0.tgz is not the right version to control chrome 87.0.4280.

Check this page for the chromdriver version you need https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_87.0.4280

Comment: Thank you for your response and  based on what you said, this is what i did:

Comment: Thank you for your response and  based on what you said, this is what i did:

Download the chromedriver_win32.zip : 87.0.4280.20 
npm install http://url/chromedriver-87.0.0.tgz

About the capabilities, I'm using the multicapabilities in the protractor.conf.js file

It's still the same result :(

Comment: multicapabilities meaning you're opening multiple browsers? if yes which ones are they